# Preload script not loading in electron@5.0.0 browserview

Tags: electron, preload

I tried loading a preload script inside browserview. According to the documentation browserview accepts the same arguments as the browserwindow accepts. But the preload script not gets loaded in the view, not either an error message in the console.

I inspected the command line of the new process, which also does not show a preload arguments. can anyone help me identifying where it went wrong?

Electron version: 5.0.0 , 5.0.1 also not working
OS version : Windows 10 x64

```
this.ElectronService.remote.BrowserView({ webPreferences: { preload : 'assets/preload/sample.js', nodeIntegration : false , plugins : false } })
```

Comment: preload should have absolute path to actual file where it exists.

Comment: and not sure what `remote.BrowserView` does in there - if it's accessing actual electron's browserView, it's ctor you need to create via `new BroswerView`

Comment: @OJKwon Thank you. I provided absolute path and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I used absolute path for preload script file , It doesnt work with relative path, when used inside angular/typescript.

```
preload : path.join(__dirname, '/assets/preload/sample.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem right now
The absolute path works with the backslash.
So you should have something like:

preload: __dirname + "assets\preload\preloadFile.js"

NB: i'm actualy using window. I dont know if "__dirname" returns the same type of values undepending of you OS. make sure to `console.log(__dirname)` to check it